# PHP: convert C# 64-bit timestamp to Unix Timestamp

Tags: c#, php

I am copying a C# function to PHP. In C#, a GUID, DateTime and boolean are converted to bytes. Next, the byte arrays get merged and encoded. The last step is to convert this to base64.

The array of bytes exists of the following parts:

```
GUID: 16 bytes
Timestamp: 8 bytes
Boolean: 1 byte
```

In php, I already converted the base64 and decoded the string back to bytes. I also managed to convert the first 16 bytes to the GUID. I validated the bytes PHP returned me and they are correct.

Now I am converting the 8 bytes to a timestamp in PHP. So far I have no luck. I guess the problem is the fact that it returns an int64.

**C#**

This is the C# byte array to datetime convert:

```
public DateTime Timestamp;
......
byte[] timestamp_bytes = new byte[8];
input.Read(timestamp_bytes, 0, 8);
Timestamp = DateTime.FromBinary(System.BitConverter.ToInt64(timestamp_bytes, 0));
```

And this is the C# datetime to byte array convert:

```
public DateTime Timestamp;
......
byte[] timestamp_bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(Timestamp.ToBinary());
```

When I output Timestamp.ToString(), i 'll get *23-12-2011 09:54:56* in both cases.

**PHP**

In PHP I managed to get the hex of the 8 bytes:

```
$bin = pack("C*", 119, 23, 124, 173, 103, 143, 206, 136);
$hex = unpack("H*", $bin);
```

What should I do next? I tried already some methods to convert, but I never seem to get the right answer.

**Additional info:**

The 8 bytes are: 119, 23, 124, 173, 103, 143, 206, 136

The hexstring is: 77177cad678fce88

The datetime I should get: 23-12-2011 09:54:56

php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;' returns 9223372036854775807

The C# app is not under my authority, so I cannot guarantee I can alter it

Comment: How the timestamp is created in C#? Are you sure it's a valid Unix Timestamp?

Comment: Sure, 4 bytes is enough for unix timestamp (before 2037), or add "00000000" head to combine 8 bytes, "77177cad678fce88" looks invalid ...

Comment: @lorenzo-s I added some information to the post. According to my info, the timestamp is valid. I get a valid date back.

Comment: @ZhengKai I converted the DateTime in C# also to a hex and it gave me back the same result. The first four bytes converted with hexdec() returns 1998027949, which is in the future.

Comment: where is the number "119, 23, 124, 173, 103, 143, 206, 136" from ?

Comment: @ZhengKai They are the decimal values of the 8 bytes extracted from the 64-bit binary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this in the end, where decrypted was the string after decrypting the token.

```
        $byte_array = array_slice(unpack("C*", "\0" . $decrypted), 1);

        $timestamp_array = array_slice($byte_array, 0, 8);
        $guid_array = array_slice($byte_array, 8, 16);
        $is_read_only_array = array_slice($byte_array, 24, 1);

        // CONVERT GUID
        .....

        // CONVERT TIMESTAMP
        $timestamp_hex = "";
        foreach ($timestamp_array as $byte) {
            $timestamp_hex .= pack("C*", $byte);
        }
        $timestamp = hexdec($timestamp_hex);

        // CONVERT IS READ ONLY
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at [**DateTime.ToBinary Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.tobinary.aspx) and [**DateTime.Ticks Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) documentation.

First of all, binary form of a **DateTime** represents *two* properties (Kind and Ticks), and it's not clear how they are concatenated in the binary string. Then, the **Ticks** property is the number of ***ten-millionth of a second*** elapsed since Jesus Christ has born.

So, how to proceed?

1. Try to understand how **Kind** and **Ticks** properties are binary stored. We need **Ticks**. My suggestion is to try to convert some tipical DateTime values to binary and analyze the output. Start with **DateTime.MinValue**, that should correspond to `01-01-0001 00:00:00`. You should see (I think) all zeros, except for the **Kind** value (if present).
2. Once you have a 64-bit **Ticks** value, you can get seconds using `floor($ticks / 10000000)`. And finally you have to subtract the number of seconds elapsed from year 1 to year 1970 (Unix standard), and this is a constant you can get converting the C# DateTime `01-01-1970 00:00:00` to binary...

Good luck.

Comment: So, you suggest it is not possible? Or what do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest (and I'm trying to) to first understand how (and if) the **Kind** property is stored in binary. This way we can isolate the **Ticks** property, and then make calculations on it. I'm unlucky 'cause my PHP installation is 32bit :(

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the help so far. I'll look through the documentation :)

Comment: Thanks! Pretty hard stuff, converting from one into another :) I did found some methods to convert "DateTime" to "unix timestamp".

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you will need to convert to a unix timestamp in C#, and pack this data into binary instead of the 8-byte DateTime object serialisation. 4 bytes will be adequate for this until 2038.

Borrowing (or stealing?) from [here](http://lannerd.nl/blog/archives/36), this is how you can create a Unix timestamp in C#:

```
public DateTime timestamp;
// ......
byte[] timestamp_bytes = new byte[8];
input.Read(timestamp_bytes, 0, 8);
timestamp = DateTime.FromBinary(System.BitConverter.ToInt64(timestamp_bytes, 0));

TimeSpan diff = (Timestamp - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).toLocalTime());
int unix = (int) diff.TotalSeconds;
// unix is now a signed 32 bit integer representing the Unix timestamp in a way
// that PHP will understand
```

Then in PHP, you can convert the 4 binary bytes back to an integer representing the unix timestamp like this:

```
$timestamp = unpack('N', $binaryString);
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $timestamp); // Should give 23-12-2011 09:54:56
```

Comment: It's easy if you change the input! XD Anyway @P.T. consider if it's possibile to change stored value, as Dave said!

Comment: I did not mention, but the C# application is developed by another company. So if possible, I am trying to work with what I got. Else they also need to change there whole app. Thanks for the suggestion!